# Как к сайту приделать форму оплаты через сбербанк ?

Tags: php, javascript

Как к сайту приделать форму оплаты через сбербанк ? Или можно ссылку где посмотреть.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте агрегаторы платежных систем. Они имеют хорошо документированное API на всех популярных языках, плюс предоставляют отчеты для налоговой и прочих инстанций. А так же они имеют договоренности, с множеством платежных систем и банков. Которые с вами бы ни когда не заключили договор, а с ними уже работают. Для примера, это робокасса и ей подобные.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал это ровно так, как написано у них на сайте и все работало

https://www.sberbank.ru/ru/s_m_business/bankingservice/internet_acquiring